# Как узнать, что в голосовом канале, кроме бота, больше никого нет? [discord-py]

Tags: python, discord.py, бот

Использую библиотеку `discord.py`, событие на вход/выход пользователей определять умею, а вот как узнать, что в канале больше никого нет кроме бота? Каким образом это можно реализовать?
Код для события входа/выхода привожу ниже:

```py
@Bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print(f'Пользователь {member} зашёл в канал {after.channel}')
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        print(f'Пользователь {member} вышел из канала {before.channel}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print(f'Пользователь {member} зашёл в канал {after.channel}, в канале {len(after.channel.members}')
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        print(f'Пользователь {member} вышел из канала {before.channel}, в канале {len(before.channel.members}')
```

А что бы проверить есть ли там бот то когда в канале останется только один пользователь, проверьте является ли он ботот или прост сравните айди пользователя с айди бота

Comment: также можно, после того, как бот подключится к голосовому каналу, прописать цикл `while ... else`, предварительно указав количество участников как параметр `global`